# convert a number string with commas to float

Tags: android, floating-point, string-formatting, decimalformat, parsefloat

I have a number which is in string format and I want to convert it to float with two decimals.

the number which is in string format can be similar to "1" or "1,128"(One thousand one hundred and twenty eight).

Initially i tried

```
String stringNumber = "1"; //works fine EXPECTED OUTPUT -- 1.00
String stringNumber = "1,128"// fails because it has a comma. EXPECTED OUTPUT -- 1,128.00

Float f = Float.parseFloat(stringNumber);
String s = String.format("%.2f", f);
```

before doing the Float.parseFloat I can remove the commas from the string, and at the end use format as shown below to get the commas back

```
format("% ,d", number)
```

I think for a simple thing I am doing a lot.

is there a simpler way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.
Rao

**EDIT**
So far what i got.
Input - "1,128"
using the following code converts to "1,128.0"
Only thing I am missing is an extra decimal point.
using the decimalFormat how to add an extra decimal point any idea guys?

```
String qa = "1,128";
String nocomma = qa.replace(",", "");
Float f = Float.parseFloat(nocomma);
String s = String.format("%.2f", f);

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.0#");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(f);
return yourFormattedString;
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.Use replace ,use `""` to replace `","`**

Then `parseFloat`

```
String stringNumber = "1,128";
String result = null;
result = stringNumber.replace(",","");
Float f = Float.parseFloat(result);
```

**2.Use `StringTokenizer`**

```
java.util.StringTokenizer stringNumber = new StringTokenizer("1,128", ",");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (stringNumber.hasMoreTokens()) {
    sb.append(stringNumber.nextToken());
}
Float f = Float.parseFloat(sb.toString());
```

**Edit**

```
//  edited here ,change to this 
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(f);
Log.e("DecimalFormat", yourFormattedString);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1,128.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know I can do this, but if my input is 1,128 and the parsefloat which I have done converts it to 1128.00. but my desired output is 1,128.00. I can use decimalFormatter 'DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##")' but the .00 still does not show up. I think I am not usind the decimal formatter right.

Comment: if the problem is only with the zeros at the end, than could it be of help if you convert 1,128 to string and simply add 00 at the end of it?

Comment: You can try it again.@Rao